# Sum of elements in list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([Head | Tail], TotalSum) :-
    list_sum(Tail, Sum1),
    Total = Head + Sum1.
```

This code returns `true`. If I replace `Total = Head + Sum1` with `Total is Head + Sum1`, then it will return the value. But what I should replace it with to get the result like this:

```
?- list_sum([1,2,0,3], Sum).
Sum = 1+2+0+3 ; % not to return value 6!!!
```

Comment: At least in SWI Prolog, for that to evaluate write `Total is Head + Sum1` instead of using the `=` sign. The clues to rethink this to use Tail Recursion Optimisation are valid, but if you're just trying to learn Declarative Programming they are not of the essence, as it is Reality's weakness that true declarative programming doesn't exist, and as such Prolog as any other language suffers from weaknesses such as procedural order-of-evaluation, which in this case is suboptimal.

Comment: "This code returns true." -- for which query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that in the second clause of your procedure TotalSum is never instantiated. You should have received a warning by the interpreter when consulting your code.

Here's my suggestion:

```
list_sum([Item], Item).
list_sum([Item1,Item2 | Tail], Total) :-
    list_sum([Item1+Item2|Tail], Total).
```

The first clause deals with the base case, when there is only one element left in the list, that is your result.

The second clause deals with the recursion step. It grabs the first two items of the list and performs a recursive call replacing those two items with a new term Item1+Item2.

Comment: Shouldn't the base case be the empty list?

Comment: First, there should be an arithmetic assignment, `is/2` instead of `+`. And if the list is empty - this will fail instead of returning 0.

Comment: @shybovycha: Please read the question again. OP wanted to get the expression of the sum in `Total`, not the actual sum.

Comment: @gusbro yeah, right. Then the solution is great, except the zero value at the beginning (because even in the expression form the sum of an empty list is still zero) =)

Comment: @shybovycha: I guess it's debatable wheter an empty list should give 0 as an expression or fail altogether. When I wrote that answer I thought the right thing to do was to fail, hence why I put that base case. But again, maybe someone wants to get `0` for an empty list. In that case just add a new base case (do not overwrite the one given but add another) as `list_sum([], 0)`.

Answer (score 37):

The answer is simple:

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :-
   sum_list(T, Rest),
   Sum is H + Rest.
```

This code works in only one direction - this means - it does not allow you to generate lists with that specific sum. But since the set of such lists is infinite, that would not be practical anyways.

Answer (score 6):

The program is

```
list_sum([],0).

list_sum([Head|Tail], TotalSum):-
list_sum(Tail, Sum1),
TotalSum is Head+Sum1.
```

now if the query is

```
?- list_sum([1,2,3,4], Sum).
```

answer is

```
Sum = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog `(+)/2` is a binary *infix* operator. This allows us to write `A+B` instead of `+(A,B)`.

```
?- current_op(_,yfx,+).   % left-associative binary infix operator
true.
```

`(+)/2` associates to the left, so `1+2+3` is a short for `(1+2)+3`.

`(.)/2` associates to the *right*, so `[1,2,3]` is short for `.(1,.(2,.(3,[])))`.

To get parenthesization right, we use an auxiliary predicate with an extra "accumulator" argument:

```
list_sum([X|Xs],S) :-
   list_sum0_sum(Xs,X,S).

list_sum0_sum([],    S ,S).
list_sum0_sum([X|Xs],S0,S) :-
   list_sum0_sum(Xs,S0+X,S).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_sum([1,2,0,3],S).
S = 1+2+0+3.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform a list of numbers into an additive expression, from

```
[1,2,3]
```

to

1 + 2 + 3

you could do something like this, using something like a *difference list*:

```
list_to_additive_expr( [] , 0 ).
list_to_additive_expr( [X|Xs] , X + RHS ) :-
  sum_of( Xs , RHS ).
```

Alternatively, you could use an *accumulator*:

```
list_to_additive_expr( Xs , Expr ) :-
  list_to_additive_expr( Xs , 0 , Expr )
  .

list_to_additive_expr( []     , Expr , Expr ) .
list_to_additive_expr( [X|Xs] , RHS , Expr ) :-
  sum_of( Xs , X + RHS , Expr )
  .
```

I believe you'll find the first style is not properly *tail recursive* and so won't get optimized into a loop via *tail recursion optimization* (TRO) — and so, if the list is sufficiently long, will get a stack overflow. The second approach should have TRO applied and should work for lists of any length.

What is TRO, you might ask? Here's [Wikipedia with an answer for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call):

> In computer science, a tail call is a subroutine call that happens inside another
>   procedure and that produces a return value, which is then immediately returned by the
>   calling procedure. The call site is then said to be in tail position, i.e. at the end of
>   the calling procedure. If a subroutine performs a tail call to itself, it is called
>   tail-recursive. This is a special case of recursion.
>
> Tail calls are significant because they can be implemented without adding a new stack
>   frame to the call stack. Most of the frame of the current procedure is not needed any
>   more, and it can be replaced by the frame of the tail call, modified as appropriate
>   (similar to overlay for processes, but for function calls). The program can then jump to
>   the called subroutine. Producing such code instead of a standard call sequence is called
>   tail call elimination, or tail call optimization.

Comment: TRO is talked about as TCO (Tail Call Optimization) usually.