# Prolog Code outputs False instead of Variable value

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

A predicate that would return the sum of even numbers in the list:

```
sumsq_even([], 0).
sumsq_even([FirstNum|RestOfNums], Total) :-
    sumsq_even(RestOfNums, TotalRest),
    Total is FirstNum + TotalRest :- 0 is FirstNum mod 2,  % Add Firstnum if it is even
    Total is TotalRest :- 1 is FirstNum mod 2.             % Dont add if firstnum is odd
```

First of all my code compiles but i get a syntax error: operator priority clash in line 4. Also when I try the query:

```
sumsq_even([1,3,5,2,-4,6,8,-7], Total).
```

it returns False and not the value of Total. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Prolog? Then what's with the `s` tag? Please pay attention to the tags you pick, as if you put the wrong tags the right people might ignore your question. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And note the `edit` link below the tags, which lets you edit your question to improve it. And please read [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well.

Comment: Sorry i accidentally posted with typos my bad. I have edited the post now Thanks.

Comment: And I don't think you need to use `mod`. I think you can use the "head/tail" `[FirstNum|RestOfNums]` functionality to discard every other item

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in a previous comment (deleted). To sum a list in prolog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875760/sum-of-elements-in-list-in-prolog

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think i have to use mod. Without it how would you separate between odd or even number as i only want the sum of even?

Comment: Why did you put `:-` in line 4 and 5? What is it purpose?

Comment: Isn't ':-' supposed to mean if, so only add totalRest to Total if the number (FirstNum) is even (mod 2)?

Comment: `:-` only roughly means *if* in the context of predicate definition, but not logic flow.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `:-` in your code (line 4 and 5) is not correct. In Prolog, `if A then B else C` is written as `( A -> B ; C)`. So your code should be:

```
sum_even([],S,S).
sum_even([H|T],ST,S):-
    (   0 =:= H mod 2 ->  
        SO is ST+H;
        SO = ST
    ),
    sum_even(T,SO,S).

sumsq_even(L,Total):-
    sum_even(L,0,Total).

?- sumsq_even([1,3,5,2,-4,6,8,-7], Total).
Total = 12.
```